# How to create a directory in Visual Studio Code tasks.json in windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, mkdir

I'm trying to write a task to create a directory using Visual studio Code tasks (in tasks.json) for windows users using the `mkdir` command, it's working well **except when the folder already exists**.

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "label": "(release) create build directory",
    "type": "shell",
    "linux": {
        "command": "mkdir -p ./build/release"
    },
    "windows": {
        "command": "mkdir .\\build\\release", // Not working when folder already exists !
    }
},
```

**What I tried:**
`"command": "IF NOT EXIST .\\build\\release mkdir .\\build\\release"`
But then I get the error:

```
At line:1 char:3
+ IF NOT EXIST .\build\release mkdir .\build\release
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'IF' in if statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisInIfStatement
```

If it is not possible to do it this way, is it possible to run this task by ignoring the exit code ? ( so that the tasks continue to build my project)

Environment:
Visual Studio code 1.40.2
Windows 10 Pro x64

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way of doing it by using `cmd.exe` with `/C` option (Run Command and then terminate)

```
{
    "label": "(release) create build directory",
    "type": "shell",
    "linux": {
        "command": "mkdir -p ./build/release"
    },
    "windows": {
        "command": "cmd",
        "args": ["/C", "if not exist .\\build\\release mkdir .\\build\\release"]
    }
},
```