# VSCode - how to make a new directory for debug results

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to use VSCode for C. I use gcc to compile the C file and want to store the generated executable file in a directory named "build", which is under the C file directory. However, I found that the directory must be created manually first.
How do I do to create the directory automatically before compilation?
`tasks.json`

```json
 "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\build\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "debug task"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

`lauch.json`

```json
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\build\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you add a `mkdir build` command?

Comment: But I don't know where I should add the `mkdir build` command.

Comment: why would you use the gcc and c and c++ tags if your issues are really only specific to VS Code ?

Comment: I think maybe it can achieved by modifying the property value of a certain json file under vscode directory, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @AnAnt Because I think maybe someone has the same idea with me when using VSCode and Compiling c or c++ with gcc.

Comment: Alright, as you see appropriate !

Comment: @AnAnt I am so sorry to disturb you, it's my first question, I will pay attention next time.

Comment: @staick nothing of the sort. I'm not disturbed. I'm only trying to help you stay clear of avoidable downvotes and flags , as I have had had happend when using only loosely related tags back when I was new. Given that logic of yours, I can see the point :)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119561/how-to-create-a-directory-in-visual-studio-code-tasks-json-in-windows) help?

Comment: @icebp Thank you so much,  It works well, [Tasks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) is also useful.